# Change size of axis ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble with my x-axis: I have a bunch of year I want to plot in a bar plot but I can't fit all the years in the x-axis (xticks). How can I reduce their size?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal example document showing how you generate your plot (do you use PGFPlots?) which demonstrates the problem?